# Why My React Native App is Slow, App is Very Small And Has Only Three Components?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have created a news app using NewsAPI.org.

The App only has three componentsthat are rendering on each of the screens.

When I open the app on my mobile phone it works very slow.

First, I thought maybe be it is slow because I have not built that app as I was using it through the expo client app on my phone.

So I build The APK file on my computer and install it on my phone but it's still very very slow.

I don't know what is the reason. This is the first react native App I have ever built.

You can find all code in the link given below.

https://snack.expo.io/@fazilmahesania/news-api

**EDITED:** Its not just about the API. The Data is loading perfectly but when i try to navigate between screens it is very slow. going from one screen to another, Opening Drawer and scrolling Flatlist all of that is working slow although the data has already loaded.

Comment: So we've ruled out Expo, it's probably just a slow API.

Comment: There are just 2 posibilities.
1. if the data is loading really slow is because of the API or your network connection
2. if the speed between screens is really slow is because of some old hardware

Comment: It's not just about the API. The data is loading perfectly but the screen transitions are very slow. when i try to navigate to one from another screen it is very slow.